# 3D array picks up unrealistic values while compiling and not the ones already set

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

The following code is the first part to simulate molecular dynamics in 3D lattices. I'm having issues with the 3D array picking up garbage values.Not at all locations, but some because of which the entire result goes wrong.I've also noticed that the error occurs when the dimension of my array is 5*5*5 onwards(for this particular simulation the least length of the cube's side should be 3). Also the code takes suspiciously longer time to complete than expected.Please comment on that issue as well if possible. And please ignore the obvious comments like what each function does, I'd done it so that I don't forget. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // has rand(),srand().
#include <ctime>   // has time.
#include <fstream> // enables file handling.
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

float rand_gen(); //full function written after main().
//int pbc(int,int,int);

int main()
{
srand((int)time(0)); //sets time as the seed for the random no. generation.
int dim=5;
int i,j,k,iup,idown,jup,jdown,kup,kdown;//indices
float x;
int l[dim][dim][dim];

float M=0.0,E=0.0;

for(i=1;i<=dim;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=dim;j++)
    {
        for(k=1;k<=dim;k++)
        {
            x=rand_gen();
            if(x<=0.5)
            {
                l[i][j][k]=-1; //sets the value in that particular location.
            }
            else
            {
                l[i][j][k]=1; //sets the value in that particular location.
            }
            M=M+l[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}

cout<<"Total magnetisation= "<<M<<endl;

for(i=1;i<=dim;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=dim;j++)
    {
        for(k=1;k<=dim;k++)
        {
            if(i==1)iup=dim;    //*********************************
            else iup=i-1;
            if(i==dim)idown=1;
            else idown=i+1;

            if(j==1)jup=dim;
            else jup=j-1;      //periodic boundary condition.
            if(j==dim)jdown=1;
            else jdown=j+1;

            if(k==1)kup=dim;
            else kup=k-1;
            if(k==dim)kdown=1;
            else kdown=k+1;    // ends here//

            E=E-(l[i][j][k]*(l[iup][j][k]+l[idown][j][k]+l[i][jup][k]+l[i][jdown][k]+l[i][j][kup]+l[i][j][kdown]))/2.0;
        }
    }
}
cout<<"Average E= "<<E/(dim*dim*dim)<<endl;
//cout<<"Testing: "<<l[5][4][3]<<" "<<l[5][4][3]<<endl;;
//**************************ALL FINE TILL HERE IT SEEMS****************************************************//
int n=100; //Number of iterations.
int no,site;
int ri,rj,rk,riup,ridown,rjup,rjdown,rkup,rkdown;
float eng=0.0,mag=M;float E_check=0.0;
float E_b4,E_aft,E_diff;
float T=4.2;
float a;

ofstream file ("Energy_check");  //file created to write the results into.
//ofstream file1 ("ENERGY1.txt");

for(no=1;no<=n;no++)
{
    for(site=1;site<=(dim*dim*dim);site++)
    {
        float v1=rand_gen();
        float v2=rand_gen();
        float v3=rand_gen();

        ri= int(v1*dim)+1;
        rj= int(v2*dim)+1;
        rk= int(v3*dim)+1;

        //if((ri>=1&&ri<=dim)&&(rj>=1&&rj<=dim)&&(rk>=1&&rk<=dim))
        {if(ri==1)riup=dim;   //periodic boundary condition like above
        else riup=ri-1;
        if(ri==dim)ridown=1;
        else ridown=ri+1;

        if(rj==1)rjup=dim;
        else rjup=rj-1;
        if(rj==dim)rjdown=1;
        else rjdown=rj+1;

        if(rk==1)rkup=dim;
        else rkup=rk-1;
        if(rk==dim)rkdown=1;
        else rkdown=rk+1;    // ends here
        }

        E_b4=-(l[ri][rj][rk]*(l[riup][rj][rk]+l[ridown][rj][rk]+l[ri][rjup][rk]+l[ri][rjdown][rk]+l[ri][rj][rkup]+l[ri][rj][rkdown]))/2.0;
        E_aft=-(E_b4);
        E_diff=-2.0*(E_b4);
        E_check=E_check+E_b4;

        if(E_diff<0)
        {
            l[ri][rj][rk]=-l[ri][rj][rk];
            eng=eng+E_diff;
            mag=mag-2*l[ri][rj][rk];
        }
        else
        {
            a=rand_gen();
            if(a<pow(exp(1.0),-E_diff/T))
            {
                l[ri][rj][rk]=-l[ri][rj][rk];
                eng=eng+E_diff;
                mag=mag-2*l[i][j][k];
            }
        }


         if(file.is_open())
        { // THE FOLLOWING CODE IS SUPPOSED TO SHOW THE VALUES OF THE ARRAY CORRESPONDING TO ITS INDICES. bUT IM GETTING GARBAGE VALUES WHEN I RUN THIS.
            file<<no<<" "<<ri<<rj<<rk<<" "<<l[ri][rj][rk]<<" "<<riup<<rj<<rk<<" "<<l[riup][rj][rk]<<" "<<ridown<<rj<<rk<<" "<<l[ridown][rj][rk]<<" "<<ri<<rjup<<rk<<" "<<l[ri][rjup][rk]<<" "<<ri<<rjdown<<rk<<" "<<l[ri][rjdown][rk]<<" "<<ri<<rj<<rkup<<" "<<l[ri][rj][rkup]<<" "<<ri<<rj<<rkdown<<" "<<l[ri][rj][rkdown]<<" "<<E_b4<<" "<<E_check<<endl;
        }
    }
    E=(E+eng)/(dim*dim*dim);
    /*if(file1.is_open())
    {
        file1<<no<<"\t"<<E<<endl;
    }*/

}
file.close();
//file1.close();
cout<<"E_check_avg= "<<E_check/(dim*dim*dim)<<endl;
return 0;
}

float rand_gen() //function to generate random number.
{
return (static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX));// random no. generated.
}
```

Comment: You *do* know that array-indexes are zero-based? I.e. they go from zero to the size minus one. In your case from `0` to `dim - 1` (inclusive).

Comment: Heads up: VLAs are not standard C++ (afaik)

Comment: Oh and technically your program is not a valid C++ program, because C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on variable length arrays? Did you mean that i can't do 'array[dim][dim][dim]' ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help guys. It started working when I changed the indexes from 0 to dim-1. But I still did not understand how my array is a variable length array, because I'm setting the value of 'dim' at its declaration and not during run-time which means the size of the array would be determined during compilation itself right?. @JoachimPileborg

Comment: The variable `dim` is a run-time variable. It doesn't matter if it's initialized only once at definition, it is still not a compile-time constant. Either mark it as `constexpr` or `const` to make it a compile-time constant.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the help :)